# Groupby and get values from another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a huge dataset arranged like this

```
Serial     Val1      Val2      Val3     
1          21.10                         
1          43.06                         
1          32.12                         
2                    11.20               
2                    22.20               
3          45.10                         
3          14.16                         
4                              34.90     
4                              12.12     
4                              18.09
```

I would like to groupby each unique serial and consolidate its corresponding values (from Val1 to Val3) to one column ['All'] and also place a  ['Source'] column.

```
Serial     Val1      Val2      Val3      All       Source
1          21.10                         21.10     Val1
1          43.06                         43.06
1          32.12                         32.12
2                    11.20               11.20     Val2
2                    22.20               22.20
3          45.10                         45.10     Val1
3          14.16                         14.16
4                              34.90     34.90     Val3
4                              12.12     12.12
4                              18.09     18.09
```

I tried doing something like this,
`df['All'] = df['Serial'].map(df.groupby('Serial').apply(lambda x: x['Val2'] if pd.isnull(x['Val1']) else x['Val3'])`

Answer (score 5):

If there is only one value filled non missing values first select columns for processing, e.g. here omit first by indexing in [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), then get `mean` with compare non mising values by [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) with [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) for column name by first `True`s, last add [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) for only first values per groups by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]
df = df.assign(All = df1.mean(axis=1),
               Source = df1.notna().idxmax(axis=1).mask(df['Serial'].duplicated()))
print (df)
   Serial   Val1  Val2   Val3    All Source
0       1  21.10   NaN    NaN  21.10   Val1
1       1  43.06   NaN    NaN  43.06    NaN
2       1  32.12   NaN    NaN  32.12    NaN
3       2    NaN  11.2    NaN  11.20   Val2
4       2    NaN  22.2    NaN  22.20    NaN
5       3  45.10   NaN    NaN  45.10   Val1
6       3  14.16   NaN    NaN  14.16    NaN
7       4    NaN   NaN  34.90  34.90   Val3
8       4    NaN   NaN  12.12  12.12    NaN
9       4    NaN   NaN  18.09  18.09    NaN
```

If possible only missing values per some row is necessary add another mask for prevent matching first `NaN` column:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]

mask = df1.isna().all(axis=1)

df = df.assign(All = df1.mean(axis=1),
               Source = df1.notna().idxmax(axis=1).mask(df['Serial'].duplicated() | mask))
print (df)
   Serial   Val1  Val2   Val3    All Source
0       1  21.10   NaN    NaN  21.10   Val1
1       1  43.06   NaN    NaN  43.06    NaN
2       1  32.12   NaN    NaN  32.12    NaN
3       2    NaN  11.2    NaN  11.20   Val2
4       2    NaN  22.2    NaN  22.20    NaN
5       3  45.10   NaN    NaN  45.10   Val1
6       3  14.16   NaN    NaN  14.16    NaN
7       4    NaN   NaN  34.90  34.90   Val3
8       4    NaN   NaN  12.12  12.12    NaN
9       5    NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Performance in small DataFrame - solution above is 329 times faster with sample data:

```
#10k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)


In [109]: %%timeit
     ...: def lastVal(row):
     ...:     lvi = row.last_valid_index()
     ...:     return pd.Series({'All': row.loc[lvi], 'Source': lvi})
     ...: 
     ...: result = df.join(df.apply(lastVal, axis=1))
     ...: result.Source = np.where(result.Source != result.Source.shift(), result.Source, '')
     ...: 
4.97 s ± 254 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [110]: %%timeit
     ...: df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]
     ...: df.assign(All = df1.mean(axis=1), Source = df1.notna().idxmax(axis=1).mask(df['Serial'].duplicated()))
     ...: 
15.1 ms ± 549 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working. Follow up question. What if there are additional columns in the dataframe but I only want to consolidate specific columns (Val1, Val2, Val3)?

Comment: @kiyaserin - Then use `df1 = df[['Val1','Val2','Val3']]` instead `df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]`

Comment: Thanks! I do have additional question. I wasn’t sure if I should create another question for this but what if there are some rows that have assigned values for multiple columns. For example, Serial 1 has values for Val1 and Val2 but I would still prefer to choose values from Val1 for the All column?

Comment: @kiyaserin - I think the best should be accept answer and create new one.

Answer (score 3):

To get values of both new columns, for each row:

- retrieve the last valid index,
- retrieve the value indicated by it,
- return the value and index, as a *Series*, with proper column names.

To to it, define the following function:

```
def lastVal(row):
    lvi = row.last_valid_index()
    return pd.Series({'All': row.loc[lvi], 'Source': lvi})
```

Then apply it and join the result with the original DataFrame:

```
result = df.join(df.apply(lastVal, axis=1))
```

The result is:

```
   Serial   Val1  Val2   Val3    All Source
0       1  21.10   NaN    NaN  21.10   Val1
1       1  43.06   NaN    NaN  43.06   Val1
2       1  32.12   NaN    NaN  32.12   Val1
3       2    NaN  11.2    NaN  11.20   Val2
4       2    NaN  22.2    NaN  22.20   Val2
5       3  45.10   NaN    NaN  45.10   Val1
6       3  14.16   NaN    NaN  14.16   Val1
7       4    NaN   NaN  34.90  34.90   Val3
8       4    NaN   NaN  12.12  12.12   Val3
9       4    NaN   NaN  18.09  18.09   Val3
```

If you are unhappy about "repeating" values in *Source* column,
run:

```
result.Source.mask(result.Source == result.Source.shift(), '', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to tackle such problem is to "Un-pivot Columns".Un-pivoting is useful for problem like yours which will make data visibility and analysis harder as the size of columns grows over time.

The way to un-pivot columns in pandas is by Using *melt* function.

Solution:

```
# return new dataframe after unpivoting columns 
df_unpivoted=df.melt(id_vars=['Series'],var_name='Source',value_name='All')
#remove null for dataframe as you have them for all value columns
df_unpivoted.dropna(inplace=True)
#try
df_unpivoted.head()
```

Additional you can now add the values columns from the old data-frame to this new one !!